# SSE1 Using divps intrinsic xmmintrin.h to divide four 32-bit floats and using printf?

Tags: c++, g++, sse, intrinsics

I need help dividing four numbers as an example and printing them. I'm using g++ as my compiler. The following code does compile with the `-msse3 -mmmx` flags, I'm not even sure I need those but it works. I know I have to [set](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-7EC08804-66F5-4F9C-95AC-32546F8BCD9B.htm) the numbers with a function call before dividing but I'm not positive which function to call (I think the link has the set functions for only `int`). If there is a way to print the result using `std::cout` that would be better but `printf` works fine for this (I'm not sure if the `print128_num` is correct for this case, it was written for `int` originally). Heres the code.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print128_num(__m128i var)
{
    uint16_t *val = (uint16_t*) &var;
    printf("Numerical: %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i \n",
       val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5],
       val[6], val[7]);
}
__m128 divide_4_32_bit_values(__m128 __A, __m128 __B)
{
    return _mm_div_ps (__A, __B);
}
int main(void)
{


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to print 4 `float`s as 8 `int16`s?

Comment: No I'm not thats what I wrote at the end of the post that maybe its wrong. So I need to fix that for 4 floats?

Comment: Wait, so you're asking how to change the `printf()` to print 4 `float`s instead of what you have there?

Comment: Yes and also how to use the correct `set` function before calling the `divide_4_32_bit_values`.

Comment: This code is truly wtf.

Comment: @CoryNelson well its pretty simple. I want to use intrinsics to set the 8 numbers to divide and pass it into the function `divide_4_32_bit_values` and return 4 variables to print. The part I don't have is the function call to set the 8 numbers and the correct print function to print the 4 floats as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed a few problems and I think this now does what you want:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print128_num(const char * label, __m128 var)
{
    float *val = (float *) &var;
    printf("%s: %f %f %f %f\n",
       label, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
}

__m128 divide_4_32_bit_values(__m128 __A, __m128 __B)
{
    return _mm_div_ps (__A, __B);
}

int main(void)
{
    __m128 v1 = _mm_set_ps(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    __m128 v2 = _mm_set_ps(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
    __m128 v = divide_4_32_bit_values(v1, v2);

    print128_num("v1", v1);
    print128_num("v2", v2);
    print128_num("v ", v);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -msse3 m128_print.c 
$ ./a.out
v1: 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
v2: 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000
v : 0.250000 0.666667 1.500000 4.000000
$
```

Comment: Do I always just place `_ps` after `_mm_set` to to get the correct setting function for using a function along the lines of `_mm_div_ps`, assuming the number of values for both operations are correctly placed?

Comment: Yes, the `_ps` suffix is found on all single precision (float) intrinsics - it stands for "(p)acked (s)ingle precision".